# Selecting all rows and columns based on dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So I have a large dataframe with a bunch of info based on states. I only want to use certain states, which I put into a dictionary.

I put index there because the names of the states are in that column. Is there a way to just select all rows and columns with the states name, with the info it has. I think the way i used does not select all of the info.\

Comment: can you provide an excerpt from your `states` variable?  What does it include?

Comment: It is this code here, but it is only the 50 states http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577305-python-dictionary-of-us-states-and-territories/

Comment: Can you also provide an example of `data_`?  And what is your end goal that you are trying to achieve?  Should `USA` be a dictionary of all the states from the `data_` variable?

Comment: I just put part of the dataframe in the original post

Comment: You can put the states into a list `states = ['a', 'b', 'c']` then use the .ix function. `data_.ix[states]` this will select the states in the list

Comment: I decided to not do the dictionary but when I do data_.ix[states] it gives me the error: IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: Try `data_.ix[states.values()]`. Otherwise you are passing in the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [a freely available CSV file with state data](http://www.downloadexcelfiles.com/sites/default/files/docs/list-states-us-36j.csv) and saved it to `states.csv`. I was able to select rows given a list of states like this:

```
import pandas as pd

states = ['New York', 'California']

df = pd.read_csv('states.csv')
df['Population'] = df['Population est.'].str.split(',').str.join('').astype(int)

df1 = df.loc[df['State'].isin(states)]

print df1[['State', 'Capital', 'Population']]
```

**Output**

```
         State     Capital  Population
4   California  Sacramento    38041430
31    New York      Albany    19570261
```